# How to convert an InputStream object to a File object?

Tags: java, html, file, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get a "File" instance in a servlet called from a html form, in which I can select a PDF file on my computer. 
I'm successful in getting the file as an "InputStream" but then I just cannot further convert it to a "File" object.

After a lot of different attempts, I still can't figure out what I should be doing to make it work. Any idea ?

Error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.pdf (Read-only file system)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:360)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openOutputStream(FileUtils.java:319)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyToFile(FileUtils.java:1552)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1528)
```

Code :

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();

if (fileContent != null)
{      
    File file = new File(filename.trim() + ".pdf");
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fileContent, file);

    //use the "file" instance
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception is telling you, the problem is not with "creating the file". The problem is **the disk/partition is write-protected**

You should create the file on a file system that is writable. Try to specify an absolute path, such as

```
File file = new File("/tmp/" + filename.trim() + ".pdf");
//or
file = new File("/home/userhome/" + filename.trim() + ".pdf");
```

The file should just be created on a writable file system.